# My procedure deletes all rows when I use delete statement

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, row, procedure

That's my table:

```
create table if not exists Ditte(nome varchar(30), luogo varchar(30), ZIP int);
```

That's my procedure:

```
delimiter // 
create procedure deleteDitta(zip int)
begin
DECLARE newZIP int;
SET newZIP = zip;
DELETE from Ditte where ZIP = newZIP;
end;
// 
delimiter ;
```

This is what I added in my table:

```
insert ignore into Ditte values ("Ditta1", "city1", 6828);
insert ignore into Ditte values ("Ditta2", "city2", 12345);
```

When I call my procedure `deleteDitta` and I put "12345" as parameter (like this: `call deleteDitta(12345);`), the procedure should deletes only the second row in table "Ditte", but it deletes all the contents of the table.
How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be MySQL getting confused about column names and variable names. Changing your procedure to this fixes the problem:

```
create procedure deleteDitta(dzip int)
begin
    DELETE from Ditte where ZIP = dzip;
end;
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5f9c4652412975c0b6a527f780984a81)